# P5,js won't run draw function

Tags: p5.js

I am trying to run p5.js script via an index html file, but it only creates the canvas, and doesn't run the draw function. Here is the html from the index.html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <script src="samplesquares.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the js from the samplesquares.js file:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  var randm = 0, color1 = 0;
  background(220);
  randm = random();
  if (randm <0.33){
     color1= color(0, 114, 206);
     }else if (randm <0.66){
     color1= color(240, 84, 84);
     }else{
     color1= color(48, 71, 94);
     }
  fill(color1);
  square(100, 80, 200, 80);
}
```

It appears to create the canvas, but doesn't run the draw function.  I think its a pretty basic error, appreciate any help.

I opened the index.html file locally and also via Web Server for Chrome, and got the same output both times.

Comment: It does call the `draw()` function. It gives me the following error: `square is not defined`.

Comment: Changing the version of `p5.js` from `0.5.11` to `1.5.0` (latest) makes the error go away.

Comment: 0.5.11 is very outdated, from 2017. Any reason why you're using that? Please share a [mcve]. `square` was not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the version of `p5.js` from `0.5.11` to `1.5.0` (latest) resolves the error for me:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I don't think you need `addons/p5.dom.min.js` anymore.